# Firebase: use updated profile with onAuthStateChanged()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I have a little twisted problem with my React app. I'm using Firebase for authentication. What I need to do is to register a user and set their `displayName` immediately. Entire problem could be avoided if Firebase allowed to call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` without signing user in, but it doesn't.

I do this:

```js
const submitHandler = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const auth = await firebase.auth();

    const { user } = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    await user.updateProfile({
        displayName: userName
    });
};
```

The problem is that I'm using `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` in my root component to handle current user state, so it's called as soon as `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` is done, before the profile is updated. I'm not sure how to tell `onAuthStateChanged()` about the updated `displayName`.

I managed to create a working solution, but I'm not happy with it. I tricked `onAuthStateChanged()` to ignore users without `displayName` like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeAuth = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user === null || user.displayName !== null) {
            setLoggedInUser(user);
        }
    });

    return () => unsubscribeAuth();
}, []);
```

And in my sign up component, I do this:

```js
const submitHandler = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const auth = await firebase.auth();

    const { user } = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    await user.updateProfile({
        displayName: userName
    });
    await auth.signOut();
    await auth.updateCurrentUser(user);
};
```

That's obviously hackish and slower than necessary, because I'm signing in twice. It works as intended though, ignoring the auto-login, then signing out (doing nothing, as the user state hasn't been updated before) and then signing in, triggering `onAuthStateChanged()` with the updated user.

How can I improve my app to sign up users without this double madness?

Answer (score 0):

Updating the user profile not normally execute the `onAuthStateChange` listener, as (usually) the authentication **state** won't change because of this API call.

You can [force a reload of the user's ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reload) to get their latest profile information.

Comment: Hmm, `user.reload()` doesn't trigger `onAuthStateChange()` for me neither.

Comment: By the way, I edited my question to use `updateCurrentUser(user)` instead of calling `signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`. If I log out before updating the current user, it does trigger `onAuthStateChange()`.

Comment: As said: the auth state hasn't changed, so the `onAuthStateChanged` won't fire. That is working as intended, and can't be changed. But you can call `setLoggedInUser(firebase.auth().currentUser);` after changing the profile to update your state/UI.

Comment: No, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're actually asking in that case: updating the user profile as you do doesn't change the user's authentication *state*, so it won't trigger the auth state listener. If you just want the profile to be updated, you can force a reload of the ID token. That also won't call the auth state listener, as (again) the auth state doesn't change. But it will get you a `user` object with the latest profile information. If you want a listener that triggers, try listening for `onIdTokenChanged`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged.